# GCS Python lib blob.download_as_bytes() vs blob.upload_from_string

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to implement pretty simple flow - download gzipped file from GCS, process it and upload it back.

I had no issues with the first part, since blob.download_as_bytes() not only downloads the file but also inflates it on the fly, so the result of this method is serialized object, that I only need to deserialize.

My problem is with blob.upload_from_string. I have written the following code:

```
def download_object(blob: storage.Blob)
    bytes_buffer = blob.download_as_bytes()
    dict_data = orjson.loads(bytes_buffer)
    return load_from_dict(dict_data)

def upload_object(blob: storage.Blob, obj)
    dict_data = obj.save_as_dict()
    json_string = orjson.dumps(dict_data).decode("utf-8")
    compressed = gzip.compress(json_string.encode("utf-8"))
    blob.upload_from_string(compressed)
```

With this code I'm able to download and reupload back file, which was gziped on upload via gsutil cli previously with following command:

`gsutil cp -Z ~/data.json gs://bucket/`

But when I try to repeat the flow for the resulting file (which is present and by size, seems to be gziped) I'm getting an error on download_object for line

`dict_data = orjson.loads(bytes_buffer)`

```
orjson.JSONDecodeError: str is not valid UTF-8: surrogates not allowed: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

What should `upload_object` look like to do the same as gsutil command does?

Comment: Where does the error happen?  In the download function?  In the upload function?  Possibly somewhere else?  We can't tell.  Don't make us guess.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Comment: You are right, I have added more details to make it clear. Cannot attach the stack, as this is not a real code, but a simplification of what is actually happening, so real stack trace would be very confusing here.

Comment: Include the `gsutil` command that is compressing and uploading the object. What is the object's metadata for [Content-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding)? Your example does not match what gsutil does. Update your post. Are you asking about the method differences or showing a bug with upload/download? Update your post to ask one question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @John Hanley for his question regarding metadata, this is exactly what I was missing. The proper solution would be:

```
def download_object(blob: storage.Blob)
    bytes_buffer = blob.download_as_bytes()
    dict_data = orjson.loads(bytes_buffer)
    return load_from_dict(dict_data)

def upload_object(blob: storage.Blob, obj)
    dict_data = obj.save_as_dict()
    json_string = orjson.dumps(dict_data)
    compressed = gzip.compress(json_string)
    blob.content_encoding = "gzip" # <- This line made all the difference
    blob.upload_from_string(compressed, "application/json")
```